# to_enum(:scan) vs scan alone with regular expression in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, match, enumerable

I dont understand why we use to_enum to make the string enumerable when the scan method would return an array of matches itself, what to_enum doing in this case?

this is the code with to_enum:

```
string = "The quick 12 brown foxes jumped over the 10 lazy dogs"

p string.to_enum(:scan, /\d+/).map {Regexp.last_match }
```

which return:

```
=> [#<MatchData "12">, #<MatchData "10">]
```

so why we use here to_enum to make the string enumerable when we can use scan which will return an array?

also I tried using scan alone but get weird result:

```
p string.scan(/\d+/).map { Regexp.last_match}
=>[#<MatchData "10">, #<MatchData "10">]
```

There is something I missing and not understanding here... can anyone explain it please?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`to_enum` isn't making the string enumerable, it's actually making `String#scan` a lazy enumerator. `enum_for` is an alias of `to_enum` and that might have helped clarify things here somewhat. `map` yields each result of the scan—one at a time (lazily)—to the block, which uses the `last_match` Regexp class method to return the last, most recent match. It's a really contrived example that you're not likely to see in the wild.

Comment: ok but I still not uderstand why when we calling scan directly on string variable we get the same value in the array and not the same results as using to_enum,!!!

Comment: I don't think it is contrived, I currently came across this while working out how to convert matched data to hash and had to use to_enum(:scan) as in the following `content.to_enum(:scan, DDD_MARKUP).map { Regexp.last_match.named_captures }`